# How to compress dataframe to report temperature measurements on Yearly basis rather than on Monthly basis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I want to display the temperature change column with values on a yearly basis (rather than on monthly basis) by taking the yearly mean of the monthly values with subsequent discarding of the monthly column. I want to do this as the rest of my datasets quote values on a yearly basis and thus having monthly values does not mean anything. I tried a couple of ways but I did not get the required result. I wanted to ask if there is a way to compress the dataset and report values on a yearly basis. An image is attached for guidance: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc2iq.png). Thanks.

Comment: what columns do you have in your dataframe? do you have a year column? or is this data stored in another date column?

Comment: Can you please paste a minimal example of your data and what you have attempted? Otherwise people have to guess what you need.

Comment: @Rai Shikoh I've updated my answer to reflect the dataframe you have

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you need to use `groupby()` though how its implemented depends on how you have the date data stored

```
df = df.groupby(by=['Area', 'Year', 'Temperature Unit', 'Temperature Flag']).mean()
```

Due to the month code and area code being stored as an integers they will not be removed automatically in the `groupby()`

they can be removed with a simple `drop()` statement

```
df = df.drop(columns=['Months Code', 'Area Code'])
```

If you want to know more check out the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Edited to reflect the actual dataframe columns